# Make cards with texts and buttons dynamically

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm making Notes app. I made cards with text and buttons dynamically (Create by clicking the button). But I have problem with Changing Text on CURRENT card. For example, I have 3 cards with own texts and buttons and I want to change text on 2nd card but text is changing on the 3rd card. How can I solve this problem?

[3 cards with texts and buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PvQw.png)

[Change Text Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxLWy.png)

In the past, I've tried making list to collect texts, but i dont know how to identify current card.

full main.dart

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    import './changeTextPage.dart';

    int count = 0;
    String titlecard = '';
    String textcard = '';

    void main() => runApp(MyApp());

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Notes',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple
          ),
          home: HomePage(title: 'Notes',),
        );
      }
    }

    class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      HomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
      final title;
      @override
      HomePageState createState() => HomePageState();
    }

    class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        List<Widget> cards = new List.generate(count, (int i) => new MyCard());

        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Notes'),
          ),
          body: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (context, constraint) {
            return Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 650.0,
                  child: new ListView(
                    children: cards,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => changeText())
                );

              });
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    class MyCard extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      myCard createState() => myCard();
    }

    class myCard extends State<MyCard> {
      int myCount = count;

      void click() {
        setState(() {
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => setNewText())
          );
        });

      }


      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Center(
          child: Card(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                  ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.album),
                  title: Text(titlecard),
                  subtitle: Text(textcard),
                ),
                ButtonTheme.bar( // make buttons use the appropriate styles for cards
                  child: ButtonBar(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      FlatButton(
                        child: const Text('Change Text'),
                        onPressed: click,
                      ),
                      FlatButton(
                        child: const Text('LISTEN'),
                        onPressed: () { /* ... */ },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }


    }

    class setNewText extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      SetNewText createState() => SetNewText();
    }

    class SetNewText extends State<setNewText> {
      final titleController = TextEditingController();
      final textController = TextEditingController();
      final formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

      void _submit() {
        setState(() {
          if (formkey.currentState.validate()) {
            formkey.currentState.save();
            Navigator.pop(context);
            titlecard = titleController.text;
            textcard = textController.text;

          }
        });

      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Change Title'),
            ),
            body: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Card(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                    child: Form(
                      key: formkey,
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          TextFormField(
                            controller: titleController,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Title'
                            ),
                            validator: (value) => value.length < 1 ? 'Invalid Title' : null,
                            onSaved: (value) => value = titleController.text,
                          ),
                          TextFormField(
                            controller: textController,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Text'
                            ),
                            validator: (text) => text.length < 1 ? 'Invalid Text' : null,
                            onSaved: (text) => text = textController.text,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  textColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                  child: Text('SUBMIT'),
                  onPressed: _submit,
                ),
              ],
            )
        );
      }


    }
```

changeTextPage.dart

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import './main.dart';

    class changeText extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      ChangeText createState() => ChangeText();
    }

    class ChangeText extends State<changeText> {
      myCard s = myCard();
      final titleController = TextEditingController();
      final textController = TextEditingController();
      final formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

      void _submit() {
        setState(() {
          if (formkey.currentState.validate()) {
            formkey.currentState.save();
            Navigator.pop(context);
            count++;
            titlecard = titleController.text;
            textcard = textController.text;
          }
        });

      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Change Title'),
          ),
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Card(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                  child: Form(
                    key: formkey,
                    child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          TextFormField(
                            controller: titleController,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Title'
                            ),
                            validator: (value) => value.length < 1 ? 'Invalid Title' : null,
                            onSaved: (value) => value = titleController.text,
                          ),
                          TextFormField(
                            controller: textController,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Text'
                            ),
                            validator: (text) => text.length < 1 ? 'Invalid Text' : null,
                            onSaved: (text) => text = textController.text,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                  ),
                  ),
                ),
              FlatButton(
                textColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                child: Text('SUBMIT'),
                onPressed: _submit,
              ),
            ],
          )
        );
      }


    }
```

Comment: I wanted to help, but looks like you trimmed important pieces of code. For example, in ChangeText class you assign to `titlecard` and `textcard`, but those fields aren't present in code. Can you provide full code in order to help?

Comment: Sure, I edited to full code. ;) P.S. Dont mind some wierd things, I just have been trying to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so you happen to make some common mistakes, one of which is critical.

- most importantly **don't use global variables!** As you do with `count`, `titlecard` and `textcard`.
- there is a practice to name stateful widgets with PascalCase and corresponding states just like the widget but prefixed with an underscore (`_`) to make it private and suffixed by the `State` word.

The correct approach for this (or one of them) would be to have a widget that would be your screen with a form to edit stuff and it would pop some struct with user values on submit:

```dart
class ChangeTextScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  _ChangeTextScreenState createState() => _ChangeTextScreenState();
}

class _ChangeTextScreenState extends State<ChangeTextScreen> {
  void _submit() {
    setState(() {
      formkey.currentState.save();

      Navigator.pop(ChangeTextResult(title: titleController.text, text: textController.text));
    });
  }

  // Rest of your code...
}

class ChangeTextResult {
  final String title;
  final String text;

  ChangeTextResult({@required this.title, @required this.text});
}
```

You should also have a place where you store your notes in some kind of a list. Your main screen looks like a good place for it. Once your app will be bigger, think about using [`scoped_model`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/scoped_model) or Redux or something.

So let's add a `Note` class and a list with your notes to your main screen:

```
class Note {
    String title;
    String text;

    Note(this.title, this.text);
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<Note> _notes = [Note('Test', 'Some test note')];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ListView cards = ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _notes.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => MyCard(
            title: _notes[index].title,
            text: _notes[index].text,
            onEdit: (title, text) => setState(() { // We'll get back to that later
                _notes[index].title = title;
                _notes[index].text = text;
            })
        ));
// (...)
```

Your `MyCard` widget (try to use better names next time) should contain some kind of information about its content, one of the best approaches would be to pass this info to its constructor, just like that:

```dart
class MyCard extends StatefulWidget {
    final String title;
    final String text;
    final Function onEdit;

    MyCard({Key key, @required this.title, @required this.text, @required this.onEdit}) : super(key: key);

    @override
    _MyCardState createState() => _MyCardState();
}
```

> Having this `Key` parameter is a good practice.

And use those parameters in your `_MyCardState` class (I renamed it from `_myCard`):

```dart
// (...)
    children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.album),
        title: Text(widget.title),
        subtitle: Text(widget.text),
    ),
// (...)
```

Returning to the moment where you open your `ChangeTextScreen`, you should assign the result of `Navigation.push()` to a variable. This is your result, you can deal with it (once we check it for `null`, the user could have returned from this screen and then the result would be `null`).

```dart
void click() {
    setState(() {
        final ChangeTextResult result = Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => ChangeTextScreen())
        );

        if (result != null) {
            widget.onEdit(result.title, result.text);
        }
    });
}
```

Do you remember that `onEdit` parameter (I mentioned it in a comment in the code above)? We call that parameter here.

---

That's it I think. I could have mixed some concepts of your app, but I think you'll manage to get my point anyways.

I quite rewrote all of your code. I think it will be easier for you to start again from scratch and have those tips in mind. Also, try to Google some similar things (like a simple Todo application) or do [Getting started from flutter.io](https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/codelab) **with part two!** That should give you a nice idea on how to resolve that common problem in Flutter.

And also, read about good practises in Flutter and Dart. Things like correctly formatting your code are really important.

BTW that's my longest answer on Stack Overflow so far. I hope you'll appreciate that.

Comment: Thanks for helping and crititizing my code! I will take your advices! I understood all things! Maybe I should watch and read more tutorials...

Comment: So, I checked you code and some errors. First, List.builder() method isnt defined for List<E> class. Second is onEdit(result.title, result.text); isnt defined for the class _MyCardState. Then, Navigator.pop(ChangeTextResult(
          title: titleController.text, text: textController.text));
    });

Comment: @SlavaLucker indeed there were some errors, I typed this code straight from the head, first two errors should be fixed, look at [post revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54401582/revisions) to see my changes. You may need to modify your `build()` method a little bit to accept a single Widget (`ListView`) instead of an array. Although I'm not sure about your third error, can you explain what is wrong?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed some error but the third says that ChangeTextResult can't be applied to BuildContext or something. I can't remember right. I will check correctly later.

Comment: It says The argument type 'ChangeTextResult' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'.     Navigator.pop(ChangeTextResult(
          title: titleController.text, text: textController.text));
    });

Comment: Finally I made this. You really helped me! I learned a lot of things in flutter! But I still dont understand why dont use global variables? Global variables means a lot in my app.

Comment: It's awesome to hear that you learned a lot! You can read [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/148109/162192) or just google why global variables are bad, it's a very broad subject :)